# need generic /home entry for Ubuntu 18.04 /etc/fstab

Tags: mount, fstab

Short version:

in /etc/fstab on an Ubuntu 18.04 system, what are the typical options used when mounting a partition as /home?  Just "defaults 0 2", or something else?

---

Longer version:

I screwed up my /etc/fstab today, but managed to get it back.  Something I was messing with basically deleted the /home entry in fstab, but I wasn't aware that it had done that, and the system kept working normally.  When I went to reboot the system (for other reasons), the system was hosed and would not even let me log in (not even on the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> console).  I eventually zero'd in on the fstab problem, recreated the missing line, and I'm now posting from that system.

But I just put in a generic line, with options="defaults", dump=0 and pass=2.  I suspect that dump and pass are fine as is, but I bet the options should be some besides the defaults. Can someone look at a vanilla 18.04 system and tell me what the options are for the /home mount?  auto_da_alloc?

I did search this forum before posting.  There's [a thread from 2011](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48635/recommended-fstab-options-for-home-partition) that says just defaults is fine, but that's 8 years old ...

---

Even longer version with background on the screwup:

I upgraded to 18.04 week ago.  I kept my /home partition, copied to a new drive, and installed the OS around that.  It had worked great for a week now.

Today I was working on setting up a backup process, and was fiddling around with mounting other drives, including an external drive.  The external drive was an existing HDD that I was putting into a brand new SATA3/USB enclosure, so my first step was to just make sure that the new enclosure worked.

The new enclosure/drive showed up in Ubuntu's Disks utility, and I could see the old partitions.  I mounted one of the partitions to confirm that worked, and ran a df (or something like that) to confirm it.

That's when I noticed that it had mounted the new partition at /home, apparently replacing the regular /home.  Uh oh, the mount operation had followed the label of the partition (and yes I now understand why).  A quick look at /home confirm that it was seeing the data on the old drive there.  Yikes!  I immediately unmounted it, and IT WENT BACK TO THE CORRECT HOME PARTITION.  The correct files showed up at /home again.  Whew, OK, don't do that again!

The system was working normally again, but what I didn't know was that in doing this, the Disks util had messed up the fstab file.  The original /home entry was gone, and now the UUID of the correct partition was associated with another mount point (more detail that I'll skip here).  The next time I rebooted, blammo, no /home.

After an hour of googling and thinking about what I had just been doing before it broke, I figured it out and restored it with a generic line in fstab.

Thanks for reading :)

Comment: If system not rebooted use /proc/mounts file to recreate fstab entries.

Comment: karthik, I'm having trouble parsing what you said.  I did some searching:

https://www.google.com/search?q=%2Fproc%2Fmounts+fstab

... and reading and still don't understand.  Does your comment relate to my question about the options, or are you pointing out how the OS still had /home mounted?

Comment: This method is explained in this link https://it.toolbox.com/question/how-to-restore-if-etc-fstab-file-is-removed-070714

Comment: Aha, thank you.  And now your original comment makes perfect sense :)

Answer (score 2):

Get UUID of partitions with `sudo blkid`
For GPT partitioned disks use `sudo sgdisk`
More information about UUID at Ubuntu Documentation : [Using UUID](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingUUID)

The 'builtin' `/home` line in `fstab` for an ext4 home partition:

```
# <file system> <mount point> <type> <options> <dump> <pass>
# /home
UUID=<a-string> /home ext4 defaults 0 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the UUID info, I got that.

Is that example from an 18.04 install?  So just "defaults 0 2" is what Ubuntu has been using for the /home mount on 18.04 installs?

Comment: @Chris C. Yes, the line is as the default one created by Ubuntu install process

Answer (score 0):

OK, it sounds like there are no special settings for the /home mount in 18.04 systems -- just use "defaults 0 2" like I said in my original post.

Thanks cmak.fr and karthik!